# JSTL iteration set a value of a selected row only not the last row's value

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
<a href="#my-id">
<s:query var="rs2" sql="select * from blah blah.. " ></s:query>
<c:forEach items="${rs2.rows}" var="data2">
<c:set var="id" value="${data2.id}" />    
${data2.name}
</c:forEach>
</a>
```

I want c:set to display the id of a selected row (name for the above code), but it only gets the last row's (loaded) id.
How to do that, please help..

ok..

explanation is:
i am using JSTL iteration to iterate over a database rows and print them in the form of table,table is printing successfully from database, but within this i want to set a variable which contains the "id of the selected row" using c:set,
but what i am getting is the id of the last row printed in the table with c:set.

please tell me how to do this..

Comment: provide more info. Not clear what are you asking?

Comment: In the code sample, I don't see any way to identify a selected row. How do you know that a particular row is selected?

Comment: @obourgain : may be this is what i don't know, or this is the thing i am doing wrong,
can you please elaborate your answer.. :)